# LiveData observing not working after Room database updates

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

My app contains a Room db of cocktail recipes that it downloads via a Retrofit api call, all of that is working well.  To focus in on where my problem lies, my use case is a user adding a cocktail to a list.  This is done via a DialogFragment and here the DialogFragment displays, the transaction executes, the DialogFragment goes away and the Room db is updated.  The cocktail fragment does not get the update though - if you navigate away and back, the update is visible so I know the transaction worked as expected.  One thing I *just* noticed is if I rotate the device, the update gets picked up as well.

Here is the relevant section of my fragment:

```
class CocktailDetailFragment : BaseFragment<CocktailDetailViewModel, FragmentCocktailDetailBinding, CocktailDetailRepository>() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.cocktail.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when(it){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    updateCocktail(it.value)
                }
            }
        })
    }

private fun updateCocktail(cocktail: Cocktail) {
        with(binding){
            detailCocktailName.text = cocktail.cocktailName
            //...
            //this is the piece of functionality i'm expecting the LiveData observer to execute and change the drawable
            if(cocktail.numLists > 0) {
                detailCocktailListImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_filled)
            } else {
                detailCocktailListImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_empty)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun getViewModel() = CocktailDetailViewModel::class.java

    override fun getFragmentBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?
    ) = FragmentCocktailDetailBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    override fun getFragmentRepository(): CocktailDetailRepository {
        val dao = GoodCallDatabase(requireContext()).goodCallDao()
        return CocktailDetailRepository(dao)
    }
}
```

BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM: BaseViewModel, B: ViewBinding, R: BaseRepository>: Fragment() {

    protected lateinit var userPreferences: UserPreferences
    protected lateinit var binding: B
    protected lateinit var viewModel: VM
    protected val remoteDataSource = RemoteDataSource()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        userPreferences = UserPreferences(requireContext())
        binding = getFragmentBinding(inflater, container)
        val factory = ViewModelFactory(getFragmentRepository())
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(getViewModel())
        return binding.root
    }

    abstract fun getViewModel() : Class<VM>

    abstract fun getFragmentBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): B

    abstract fun getFragmentRepository(): R

}
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
class ViewModelFactory(
    private val repository: BaseRepository
): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return when{
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(CocktailDetailViewModel::class.java) -> CocktailDetailViewModel(repository as CocktailDetailRepository) as T
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("ViewModel class not found")
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class CocktailDetailViewModel(
    private val repository: CocktailDetailRepository
): BaseViewModel(repository) {
    private val _cocktail: MutableLiveData<Resource<Cocktail>> = MutableLiveData()
    val cocktail: LiveData<Resource<Cocktail>>
        get() = _cocktail

    fun getCocktailByCocktailId(cocktailId: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _cocktail.value = Resource.Loading
        _cocktail.value = repository.getCocktail(cocktailId)
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class CocktailDetailRepository(
    private val dao: GoodCallDao
):BaseRepository(dao) {
    suspend fun getCocktail(cocktailId: Int) = safeApiCall {
        dao.getCocktail(cocktailId)
    }
}
```

Safe Api Call (I use this so db/api calls run on IO):

```
interface SafeApiCall {
    suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(
        apiCall: suspend () -> T
    ): Resource<T> {

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                Resource.Success(apiCall.invoke())
            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                when (throwable) {
                    is HttpException -> {
                        Resource.Failure(false, throwable.code(), throwable.response()?.errorBody())
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Resource.Failure(true, null, null)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val value: T) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure(
        val isNetworkError: Boolean,
        val errorCode: Int?,
        val errorBody: ResponseBody?
    ): Resource<Nothing>()
    object Loading: Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM cocktail c WHERE c.cocktail_id = :cocktailId")
    suspend fun getCocktail(cocktailId: Int): Cocktail
```

Thank you in advance for any help!  Given the issue and how the app is working, I believe I have provided all the relevant parts but please advise if more of my code is required to figure this out.

Comment: no need to explain your level of experience here, a good answer should be something everyone can understand and if you can't understand an answer, you can add comments to it

Comment: your problem probably doesn't lie anywhere here, because this code you already said is working, right ? instead of `CocktailDetailFragment`, do you have a `CocktailFragment` where you're expecting this update, where it isn't showing ?

Comment: In `viewModel.cocktail.observe`, why not check if you received a `Loading` or `Failure`?

Comment: @a_local_nobody - it works but it doesn't update when the data that's being displayed by `CocktailDetailFragment` is updated.  I don't have a `CocktailFragment`, the lack of update of LiveData is happening in `CocktailDetailFragment`.  As mentioned, without navigating away from the fragment but rotating the device the expected update happens.

Comment: @rupinderjeet - mostly lazy at the moment just trying to get all the functionality working, i have todo's to handle those states in a lot of places.